# CATiledLayer Equivalent on Android

Tags: android

After going through the nightmare getting an app from completion to submitted to the the Apple App Store (waiting on approval, I am inspired to switch over to Android. I am looking at the high level design issues.

My app creates mosaics of maps. On IOS it uses a huge UIView (often 50,000 x 35,000) with a CATiledLayer. This allows the customer to scroll the extent of a huge mosaic or to zoom out and see the mosaic at low resolution.

Does the equivalent to CATiledLayer exist in Android?

For clarification, the maps I work with cannot be tiled. They overlap and have to be displayed at different angles. The layout changes depending upon the reference point. Using some equivalent of the map kit is not a viable option.

Let me clarify the apparent conflict. The CATiled layer allows drawing into a tile. I can draw maps that overlap the tile and still create a tile. I don't have to create thousands of image tiles and place them together.

Comment: You might check out [OSMDroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/).

Comment: I cannot use tiling maps. Mine use various projections, none being Mercator.